# Tool to listen http traffic goes to different ports (Windows)

Tags: http, java, ports, rest, monitoring

I am using a set of microservices (Spring MVC Hosted in Undertow containers along with Gradle) which are spawned on different ports in the same machine. Services make HTTP REST to each other.

I need a tool to monitor HTTP traffic between these services (same machine different ports). Please provide any recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### RawCap

While the standard approach of Wireshark won't work on Windows due to how loopback interface is(n't) implemented in Windows, you should be able to use [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) to capture the data and then analyze it in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 0):

### prometheus

I recommend this tool.
Actually, i didn't use it. however, i think it may support you in your case.
Check it [here](https://prometheus.io/).